# Dispatch Two internet connections in Ubuntu

Tags: server, internet, lan

I have two internet connections and I want to use them simultaneously in Ubuntu server to increase bandwidth and use this Ubuntu server as gateway for my LAN.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this but I've thought about it.
Isn't the bandwidth allocated at the modem/router?  You basically assign the IP's/DNS to your web servers.  Setup should be as simple as assigning two interfaces eth0,eth1 and rock and roll from there.

Answer (score 0):

In short; you can't.  The best you can do is to manually run some services, like a big download, over one connection, and other things like your web browsing over the other.